# Xamarin children add with multiple AbsoluteLayoutFlags

Tags: c#, xamarin, position

I am wandering if its possible to add multiple AbsoluteLayoutFlags to a child? when doing it in c#?

I know that it is possible in XAML:

```
StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 90"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional">
```

But when I try to do this from c# I am apparently only able to add one:

```
layout.Children.Add(topMenu(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 90), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
```

Hope to get help with this and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add OR operator between Flags

```
layout.Children.Add(topMenu, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 90), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional|AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional|AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
```

You can append `|` operator how any values available for `AbsoluteLayoutFlags` `enum`. Or you can try below one

You can add `AbsoluteLayoutFlags` to any control individually how many you need. Have a look on this sample code snippets

```
var layout = new AbsoluteLayout
{    
    BackgroundColor = Color.Blue.WithLuminosity(0.9),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};    

var topMenu = new Label
{
    Text = "Left",
    TextColor = Color.Black
};

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(topMenu,
AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None|AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(topMenu,
new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 90));

layout.Children.Add(topMenu);
```